# oData $count doesn't work with EntitySetController<TEntity, TKey> in web api 4

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm useing EntitySetController to create an oData web api controller, and everything works well, except to get the total records count.

THe controller is defined as below:

```
public class MyODataController : EntitySetController<Entity1, int> where TEntity : class
{
    public override IQueryable<Entity1> Get()
    {
        return EntityDatabase.Get();
    }
}
```

when I call the count through:

```
http://localhost:44789/oData/MyOData/$count
```

I get the error:
Invalid action detected. '$count' is not an action that can bind to 'Collection([Entity1  Nullable=False])'.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unfortunately, Web API doesn't support $count out-of-the box quite yet although it should in a future version. In the meantime, you can still add support by defining these classes:

```cs
public class CountODataRoutingConvention : EntitySetRoutingConvention
{
    public override string SelectAction(ODataPath odataPath, HttpControllerContext controllerContext, ILookup<string, HttpActionDescriptor> actionMap)
    {
        if (controllerContext.Request.Method == HttpMethod.Get && odataPath.PathTemplate == "~/entityset/$count")
        {
            if (actionMap.Contains("GetCount"))
            {
                return "GetCount";
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public class CountODataPathHandler : DefaultODataPathHandler
{
    protected override ODataPathSegment ParseAtEntityCollection(IEdmModel model, ODataPathSegment previous, IEdmType previousEdmType, string segment)
    {
        if (segment == "$count")
        {
            return new CountPathSegment();
        }
        return base.ParseAtEntityCollection(model, previous, previousEdmType, segment);
    }
}

public class CountPathSegment : ODataPathSegment
{
    public override string SegmentKind
    {
        get
        {
            return "$count";
        }
    }

    public override IEdmType GetEdmType(IEdmType previousEdmType)
    {
        return EdmCoreModel.Instance.FindDeclaredType("Edm.Int32");
    }

    public override IEdmEntitySet GetEntitySet(IEdmEntitySet previousEntitySet)
    {
        return previousEntitySet;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "$count";
    }
}
```

Registering them in MapODataRoute:

```cs
IList<IODataRoutingConvention> routingConventions = ODataRoutingConventions.CreateDefault();
routingConventions.Insert(0, new CountODataRoutingConvention());
config.Routes.MapODataRoute("OData", "odata", GetModel(), new CountODataPathHandler(), routingConventions);
```

And in your controller, adding this method:

```cs
public HttpResponseMessage GetCount(ODataQueryOptions<TEntity> queryOptions)
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> queryResults = queryOptions.ApplyTo(Get()) as IQueryable<TEntity>;
    int count = queryResults.Count();
    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    response.Content = new StringContent(count.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain");
    return response;
}
```

To avoid having to copy GetCount() to every controller, you could define a base class that derives from EntitySetController that defines GetCount.

Comment: Thank you, but if I want to get total count with filter, for example only get the total records count with the entities that matchs the filter in url, how should I do?

Comment: Good point frank. I've updated the controller code so it should work with query options like filter as well.

Comment: $count must return the total number of items in a collection (see [MS-ODATA], page 58, URI pattern #15: *MUST identify the count of all instances of the base EntityType or any of the EntityType's
subtypes within the specified EntitySet specified in the last URI segment*). If you need to count items with filter applied use $inlinecount.

Comment: Anton, the problem with inlinecount is that it returns all of the data as well, which in my case is a great deal. I want to simply get a count of the entities that meet the filter WITHOUT the actual data so that I can manage the transfer efficiently on the client side. I don't think that runs counter to the above statement from [MS-ODATA]...

Comment: inline count is supposed to be after the filter, count is supposed to be before the query filter (but the total possible(so after all your authenticaltion filtering etc))

Comment: GetModel() is not valid, where are we supposed to put the middle code exactly? I tried my WebApi Config...

Answer (score 7):

If you use the following:

```
http://localhost:44789/oData/MyOData?$inlinecount=allpages
```

then the total count will be included in your get return.

Comment: Thank you, but I have tried, and the allpages returns the count without the filter, for example, if I use **/oData/MyOData$inlinecount=allpages&filter=age ge 20, it still return all the entities without the filter

Comment: Sorry, My fault, I forget to add "$" before filter, this way works

Comment: forgetting the "$" has been the bane of my existence.  I've gotten to the point where, if a odata call doesn't work as expected, I check for missing "$".

Comment: This method executes the SQL query with top 0 clause and even though nothing is returned, the query is still sent to SQL server and SQL server parses it and executes it.

Answer (score 2):

The latest package Web API 2.2 for OData v4.0 has $count support.

Answer (score 2):

localhost:..../?$inlinecount=allpages&$skip=0&$top=0
I think this is batter. You don't need add more code.

Comment: You could do with even less code: $skip=0 is not needed. Filtering still works by the way.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use $top=0 in combination with $inlinecount=allpages.  A bit of a work-around but I find it works great and I'd rather have the object returned than a single value of integer.  This works great with filter too:

```
http://localhost:44789/oData/MyOData?$filter=MyFilter&$top=1&$inlinecount=allpages
```